# Google Analytics not displaying data from GTM

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a Tag in GTM that will show as an event in GA when triggered. In addition, I'm trying to see the debug mode flow on GA that is coming from GTM in preview mode.

**Debug mode not working**
Earlier when setting up the account, I noticed the Debug Mode in GA isn't receiving any data from GTM. I tried implementing the debug_mode = true (Fields to set) in the GA4 Configuration Tag, as well as using the Google Debugger extension. Both didn't work.

**GA4 Events not working**
Although GA is reporting regular activity (sessions, engagement, etc.) it fails to gather the new GA4 event I set up in GTM. I followed a step-by-step tutorial by MeasureSchool on YT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkMRRcwEfi8) to accomplish this. Didn't work either.

**Preview mode not showing GA Container activity**
When entering "preview" mode, while the GTM container is reporting successful Tag fires, the GA is displaying a "No hits were sent by this container" message.

At this point, I am convinced there is a broken connection between GTM and GA, since quite remarkably, the two work perfectly on their own.

However, before I restart the entire process and start from scratch, I was wondering whether anyone has a clue to how this can be solved?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't completed debugging properly.

Use the network tab in chrome's devtools for debugging. Or use adswerve's datalayer debugger to get the same info in the console. Make sure you see events flowing to google's "collect" endpoint. Disable your adblockers. Make sure the tid field in the event payload is the same as your GA's property id if you still attempt to use GA UA, or it has to match your measurement id if you're using GA4.